# execution exited the loop while it supposed to stay in the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have the following code that supposed to get the IP of a server, and if the server is not reachable (return False) then it goes inside a loop until it return anything other than False.

I was testing it today while  the server was offline, it went inside the loop for a while but then suddenly it broke out of the loop with a value (False), it supposed to stay in the loop as long as it's false.

could someone please check the code? i'm new to Python and programming in general.

```
def startup_check():
    exp1_current_ip = get_exp_ip()
    if exp1_current_ip == False:
        while True:
            sleep(10)
            exp1_current_ip = get_exp_ip()
            if public_ip != False:
                break
    do_more(exp1_current_ip)



def get_exp_ip():
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        exp_login_url = ("https://10.10.10.10/login")
        network_conf_url = ("https://10.10.10.10/ip")
        login_payload = {
            "submitbutton": "Login",
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "formbutton": "Login"
        }
        login = session.post(exp_login_url, data=login_payload, verify=False)
        logging.exception(f"Loging to {exp_ip} was successful")
        network_conf = session.get(network_conf_url, verify=False)
        exp1_current_ip = str(network_conf.html.find("#ip_v4_nat_addr2")).split("'")[11]
        return exp1_current_ip
    except:
        return False


startup_check()
```

Comment: Is there a chance that the `exp1_current_ip` variable returned could be an empty string? Also, what is: `public_ip != False` in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question you posted is kind of vague, it is not clear but as far as i can see you are using a public_ip to break your loop but i dont know whether you are getting any value for public_ip from outside or not since your loop depends on it, follow up on that or if you mistaken exp1_current_ip for public_ip then replace it should work.

```
def startup_check():
    exp1_current_ip = get_exp_ip()
    if exp1_current_ip == False:
        while True:
            sleep(10)
            exp1_current_ip = get_exp_ip()
            if exp1_current_ip != False:
                break
    do_more(exp1_current_ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would be using some IDE to run this code snippet. A careful debugging may solve your purpose. That's how, I solve issues like this.